# The return value should be a list but doesn't return as expected?! - Python newbie

Tags: python

This must be a very simple solution that has eluded me this last hour.  I've tried to build this test function where the return value of the test_cases list should match the values in the test_case_answers list but for some reason, test case 1 and test case 2 fail.  When I print the return values for the test cases they return the correct answers, but for some reason test case 1 and test case 2 return False.

```
import math

test_cases = [1, 9, -3]  
test_case_answers = [1, 3, 0]

def custom_sqrt(num):  
    for i in range(len(test_cases)):  
        if test_cases[i] >= 0:  
            return math.sqrt(test_cases[i])  
        else:  
            return 0

for i in range(len(test_cases)):  
    if custom_sqrt(test_cases[i]) != test_case_answers[i]:  
        print "Test Case #", i, "failed!"


custom_sqrt(test_cases)
```

Comment: Is that `custom_sqrt(test_cases)` at the bottom actually there? Just curious.

Comment: Why do you expect it to return a list? The code here clearly returns only a single integer, and the caller compares each return value to a single integer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping too many times.  In `custom_sqrt`, you try to loop over all test cases, but you return the value for the first one, so you never get to the rest.  Remove your loop from `custom_sqrt` so it's just:

```
def custom_sqrt(num):
    if num >= 0:
        return math.sqrt(num)
    else: 
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `custom_sqrt` function is expecting a list of integers and you are giving it a single integer.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the test inside your function is probably not a good idea; you have to remove it once you're done, and then the function is no longer the same one you tested!

```
import math

def test_fn(fn, data):
    for inp, exp in data:
        outp = fn(inp)
        if outp == exp:
            print("  passed")
        else:
            print("*** FAILED: {}({}) returned {}, should be {}".format(fn.__name__, inp, outp, exp))

def custom_sqrt_a(num):
    try:
        return math.sqrt(num)
    except ValueError:
        return 0.

def custom_sqrt_b(num):
    if num < 0.:
        return 0.
    else:
        return math.sqrt(num)

custom_sqrt_test_data = [
    ( 1., 1.),
    ( 9., 3.),
    (-3., 0.)
]
test_fn(custom_sqrt_a, custom_sqrt_test_data)
test_fn(custom_sqrt_b, custom_sqrt_test_data)
```